# Is there any difference using this or passing a parameter object

Tags: java, methods, parameters, this

Let's say I have a method that goes:

```
public void boolean isEndingStation(Station station, BusLine busLine){
...
}
```

which is inside a `BusLine` class.
Is there any difference if I just use the object that's calling the function **without** the `BusLine` parameter using the `this` keyword?

Example of what I mean:

```
public void boolean isEndingStation(Station station){
this.[code]
...
}
```

Passing an argument like the first example seems redundant and overall makes the method look messier.

Comment: It’s not really clear what you mean. Can you explain using a concrete example?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I expanded my question. I hope it's better now

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not it's "redundant" depends on how it's being used.

If you're asking a specific instance of `BusLine` if the provided `Station` is an "ending station" then yes, it's redundant, and supremely confusing.

Same way it'd be confusing if you asked a `Station` if it was an "ending station" for a given `BusLine`, e.g., `station.isEndingStationFor(aBusLine)` taking a `Station` wouldn't make sense.

If it was a *static* method, e.g., `Station.isStationEndStation(aStation, aBusline)` then it makes sense.

This is one of the things Java-style OOP is designed to do: sending messages ("calling methods") on instances of classes. Inside those functions use instance data to do something meaningful with that message.

It might even make sense to have `isEndingStation` make a method call to the `Station`, e.g.,

```
public void boolean isEndingStation(Station station) {
    return station.isEndFor(this);
}
```

Ultimately what makes the *most* sense depends on where functionality lives, how you want to access it, how the system is architected, etc.

Comment: So it would make more sense if the method itself is static, in that case both objects are necessary. My ArrayList of Station(s) is inside a BusLine class and the Station itself(and its instances) doesn't know anything about BusLine methods. The method was basically checking if the corresponding Station is at the last place in the array, if it is, return true.

Comment: If a `BusLine` has a list of its stations then it could still be `busLine.isEndStation(station)` and the `BusLine` would just check the last element in the array of stations to see if it matches `station` (assuming they're in order like that), e.g., in pseudo-code, `return this.lastStation.equals(station)`